# Python - How to retrieve element from json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, jsonpath

Aloha,

My python routine will retrieve json from site, then check the file and download another json given the first answer and eventually download a zip.
The first json file gives information about doc.
Here's an example :

```
[
    {
        "id": "d9789918772f935b2d686f523d066a7b",
        "originalName": "130010259_AC2_R44_20200101",
        "type": "SUP",
        "status": "document.deleted",
        "legalStatus": "APPROVED",
        "name": "130010259_SUP_R44_AC2",
        "grid": {
            "name": "R44",
            "title": "GRAND EST"
        },
        "bbox": [
            3.4212881,
            47.6171589,
            8.1598899,
            50.1338684
        ],
        "documentSource": "UPLOAD",
        "uploadDate": "2020-06-25T14:56:27+02:00",
        "updateDate": "2021-01-19T14:33:35+01:00",
        "fileIdentifier": "SUP-AC2-R44-130010259-20200101",
        "legalControlStatus": 101
    },
    {
        "id": "6a9013bdde6acfa632861aeb1a02942b",
        "originalName": "130010259_AC2_R44_20210101",
        "type": "SUP",
        "status": "document.production",
        "legalStatus": "APPROVED",
        "name": "130010259_SUP_R44_AC2",
        "grid": {
            "name": "R44",
            "title": "GRAND EST"
        },
        "bbox": [
            3.4212881,
            47.6171589,
            8.1598899,
            50.1338684
        ],
        "documentSource": "UPLOAD",
        "uploadDate": "2021-01-18T16:37:01+01:00",
        "updateDate": "2021-01-19T14:33:29+01:00",
        "fileIdentifier": "SUP-AC2-R44-130010259-20210101",
        "legalControlStatus": 101
    },
    {
        "id": "efd51feaf35b12248966cb82f603e403",
        "originalName": "130010259_PM2_R44_20210101",
        "type": "SUP",
        "status": "document.production",
        "legalStatus": "APPROVED",
        "name": "130010259_SUP_R44_PM2",
        "grid": {
            "name": "R44",
            "title": "GRAND EST"
        },
        "bbox": [
            3.6535762,
            47.665021,
            7.9509455,
            49.907347
        ],
        "documentSource": "UPLOAD",
        "uploadDate": "2021-01-28T09:52:31+01:00",
        "updateDate": "2021-01-28T18:53:34+01:00",
        "fileIdentifier": "SUP-PM2-R44-130010259-20210101",
        "legalControlStatus": 101
    },
    {
        "id": "2e1b6104fdc09c84077d54fd9e74a7a7",
        "originalName": "444619258_I4_R44_20210211",
        "type": "SUP",
        "status": "document.pre_production",
        "legalStatus": "APPROVED",
        "name": "444619258_SUP_R44_I4",
        "grid": {
            "name": "R44",
            "title": "GRAND EST"
        },
        "bbox": [
            2.8698336,
            47.3373246,
            8.0881368,
            50.3796449
        ],
        "documentSource": "UPLOAD",
        "uploadDate": "2021-04-19T10:20:20+02:00",
        "updateDate": "2021-04-19T14:46:21+02:00",
        "fileIdentifier": "SUP-I4-R44-444619258-20210211",
        "legalControlStatus": 100
    }
]
```

What I try to do is to retrieve "id" from this json file. (ex. "id": "2e1b6104fdc09c84077d54fd9e74a7a7",)

I've tried

```
import json
from jsonpath_rw import jsonpath, parse
import jsonpath_rw_ext as jp

with open('C:/temp/gpu/SUP/20210419/SUPGE.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    data = json.dumps(d)
    print("oriName: {}".format( jp.match1("$.id[*]",data) ) )
```

It doesn't work In fact, I'm not sure how jsonpath-rw is intended to work. Thankfully there was [this blogpost](https://fabianlee.org/2019/03/10/python-querying-json-files-with-jsonpath-using-jsonpath_rw_ext/) But I'm still stuck.

Does anyone have a clue ?

With the id, I'll be able to download another json and in this json there'll be an archiveUrl to get the zipfile.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just cut out the middleman and `print([i['id'] for i in d])`?

Comment: Thanks. Now, the trick : how could I get "id" only if "status"="document.production" ?

Comment: `print([i['id'] for i in d if i['status'] == 'document.production'])`?

Comment: If I use your proposition, i get 4 lists with same 2 id.
So I rewrote :
```file = open('C:/temp/gpu/SUP/20210419\SUPGE.json')
with file as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    for i in d:
        if i['status'] == 'document.production' :
             print('status production',i.get('id') )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import  json

file = open('SUPGE.json')


with file as f:

    d = json.load(f)
    for i in d:
        print(i.get('id'))
```

this will give you id only.

d9789918772f935b2d686f523d066a7b
6a9013bdde6acfa632861aeb1a02942b
efd51feaf35b12248966cb82f603e403
2e1b6104fdc09c84077d54fd9e74a7a7

Comment: Thanks. Now, the trick : how could I get "id" only if "status"="document.production" ?

Comment: `import  json

file = open('SUPGE.json')

with file as f:

    d = json.load(f)
    for i in d:
        if i.get('status') =='document.production':
            print (i.get('id')) `

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

Here's what I've done.

```
import json
import urllib

# not sure it's the best way to load json from url, but it works fine 
# and I could test most of code if needed.
def getResponse(url):
    operUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    if(operUrl.getcode()==200):
        data = operUrl.read()
        jsonData = json.loads(data)
    else:
        print("Erreur reçue", operUrl.getcode())
    return jsonData

# Here I get the json from the url. *
# That part will be in the final script a parameter, 
# because I got lot of territory to control
d = getResponse('https://www.geoportail-urbanisme.gouv.fr/api/document?documentFamily=SUP&grid=R44&legalStatus=APPROVED')
for i in d:
    if i['status'] == 'document.production' :
         print('id du doc en production :',i.get('id')) 
# here we parse the id to fetch the whole document. 
# Same server, same API but different url
         _URL = 'https://www.geoportail-urbanisme.gouv.fr/api/document/' + i.get('id')+'/details'
         d2 = getResponse(_URL)
         print('archive',d2['archiveUrl'])
         urllib.request.urlretrieve(d2['archiveUrl'], 'c:/temp/gpu/SUP/'+d2['metadata']+'.zip' )
                 
# I used wget in the past and loved the progression bar. 
# Maybe I'd switch to wget because of it. 
# Works fine.
```

Thanks for your answer. I'm delighted to see that even with only the json library you could do **amazing** things. *Just normal stuff*. **But amazing**.
Feel free to comment if you think I've missed smthg.